# reading data from xls, making xls file corrupted in selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read data from a xls which is working fine using

```
   java.io.File f1=new java.io.File("E:/SELENIUM DATA/First_P1/DATA_SHEET.xls");
   w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f1);
   wworkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(f1,w);
```

after some time , if try to open xls , showing file is corrupted. help me.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your small piece of code it seems you are not following the correct way to read the excel sheet. If you just want to read the excel sheet then there is no need to use `createWorkbook(f1,w)` or If you want to write something on it then you must be doing something wrong that's why it corrupts your file.

[Read/Write Excel sheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

The file should be closed properly once the data read/write from the sheet so that
the mentioned error message will not be prompted.

You can use below commands like

```
w.write();
w.close();
```